# GraphQL - JWT -change payload of verifyToken mutation - django

Tags: django, graphql, jwt, token, graphene-python

I wanna change the payload of verifyToken mutation. So instead of returning email I wanna return id or the whole object

**schema.py**

```
import graphql_jwt
class Query(AccountsQuery, ObjectType):
    # This class will inherit from multiple Queries
    # as we begin to add more apps to our project
    pass

 
class Mutation( AccountsMutation, ObjectType):
    # This class will inherit from multiple Mutations 
    # as we begin to add more apps to our project
    token_auth = graphql_jwt.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()
    verify_token = graphql_jwt.Verify.Field()
    refresh_token = graphql_jwt.Refresh.Field()
    pass  


schema = Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

[image]

I've seen this: https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/en/latest/_modules/graphql_jwt/utils.html#get_user_by_natural_key

But I dont know how I can implement that - if it's a correct approach

Any ideas how I could do that?

Answer (score 2):

To modify the payload of your token, you have to create a custom `jwt_payload` function and you must add the path of the function to the `JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER` in your `settings.GRAPHQL_JWT`

**projectname.settings.py**

```
GRAPHQL_JWT = {
    ...
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'polls.schema.jwt_payload',
    ...
}
```

**polls.schema.py**

```
import graphql_jwt
from datetime import datetime
from projectname.settings import GRAPHQL_JWT
        
def jwt_payload(user, context=None):
    username = user.get_username()
    
    payload = {
        user.USERNAME_FIELD: username,
        'user_id': user.id,
        'email': user.email,
        'phone': user.phone,
        'exp': datetime.utcnow() + GRAPHQL_JWT['JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA'],
        ...    
    }
```

[original jwt payload function](https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/en/latest/_modules/graphql_jwt/utils.html#jwt_payload)

> Note that in your case the `user.USERNAME_FIELD` is your email field, it's the default field in your payload (it's also the field you need to get the token), you can remove it or you can edit it by following the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model), if you declare a custom `USERNAME_FIELD` you can choose from all columns in the 'auth_user' table, but you have to declare it bevor you run `python manage.py migrate` for the first time